# Requesting code recommendations for building a multi-layered, conversation bot

Tags: c#, botframework

My company wants an Azure bot to respond to a series of “yes” and “no” answers along a conversational path with three layers. I'm using **Visual Studio Community 2019** to edit code and **Bot Framework Emulator (V4)** to test the bot.

Here's a link to an image of the questions and answers and how the conversational flow should look:

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/5/21/738797c22a7756a01fdf6786f26eb39b-full.png.

I'm not sure know how to link multiple layers of dialogue together. I've only been able to construct a bot with one layer of dialogue as shown at the URL below:

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/5/21/99019e8e881d62f56ce449397ca9f191-full.png

I tried using the "SuggestedActionsBot" template, but it seems to need a major rework to make our deliverable possible.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/08.suggested-actions

Just for reference, here's an example of how the code for the first layer of dialogue looks:

```
private static string ProcessInput(string text)
{
    const string FirstSequenceResponseYes = "Sure, can you explain the issue? " + 
        "Do you see error message such as 'Power BI Access Tokens Not Allocated?'";
    const string FirstSequenceResponseNo = "Thanks, user. " +
        "It's good to interact with you. Have a great day!";

    switch (text)
    {
        case "yes":
        {
            return $"{FirstSequenceResponseYes}";
        }

        case "no":
        {
            return $"{FirstSequenceResponseNo}";
        }

        default:
        {
            return "Please select one of the suggested action choices.";
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to go about writing the code to make this deliverable possible? Are there URLs and resources someone could provide that are directly pertinent to what we're trying to achieve?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bit too broad for someone to be able to provide a clear and specific answer.  It somewhat comes across as "Here's a high level design for my application, how should this be implemented?" which isn't a great fit for the platform IMO.  I suggest moving forward with an approach on your own, and possibly returning with a specific question like "Why am I running into this specific error?"

Comment: Check the Multi-turn prompt sample https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt/Dialogs/UserProfileDialog.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question exactly, as the comment say.

But for navigating layers in the bot, I would encourage you to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) documentation.

With the [bot-community solution](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.ChoiceFlow), you can create a complex dialog with several levels.

Finally, in order to create a dialog that receives only yes and no answers, I would suggest using [ConfirmPrompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.confirmprompt?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable).